# Does passing a reference to onClick instead on () -> fn have real impact on performance? in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance

I was wondering if it is real because I know that React has some inside mechanism to keep everything in a good fit.
So I made a few tests:

I made component:

```js
import React from 'react';

function Stupid() {
  const [sta, setSta] = React.useState([])

  const onClick = () => {
    setSta(new Array(10000).fill("a"))
  }

  const doSmth = () => {
    const p = new Array(100).fill(0)
    const g = p.map(e => e + 1)
  }

  console.log('Rendered')

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={onClick}>KLIK</button>
      {sta.map((el, index) => {            
        return <div key={index} onClick={() => doSmth}>X</div>
        // Here I passed {doSmth} in second try so just reference

      })}
    </>
  )
}

export default Stupid;
```

Placed next to the button like this:

```js
// this is the root component
const = [details, setDetails] = useState(0)

<button onClick={() => setDetails(Math.random())}>RE_RENDER</button>
<Stupid />
```

And just click 3 times on the button "KLIK" to create 30k divs
and then I clicked on button "RE_RENDER" 3 times to create each time new functions for `onClick` in the first try.

Here are the results:

First is reference type and second is `() => fn`

So my bottom line that those results are quite similar, is it a myth, or I doing something wrong? Or Just React has really good performance and can handle some "bad code" with no problem?

[image: Reference type]

[image: () => fn type]

Comment: Would not a more accurate test be to use the same function for both cases, i.e. a test pass with `onClick={onClick}` and a second with `onClick={() => onClick()}`? This would, IMO, more clearly test the aspect of callback ref versus callback anonymous function. React has gone to great lengths to ensure it is performant, so I would imagine on any decent machine doing something a little "sub-optimal" would/should still be fairly performant. Try running these same tests on different devices, especially underpowered mobile devices.

Comment: Also, I could be mistaken, but these two images I think are identical. Checked them in a diffing tool. They are identical.